# Query string with specifying term in ElasticSearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have an index for user registrations for fast search. I need to implement search by certain fields for each event. (each event has its registrations, but of course, I'm storing them into one index)

I'm trying to search it with these parameters:

```
'query' => [
     'query_string' => [
          'query' => $query,
              'fields'=> ['name', 'lastName', 'email', ...]
           ],
      ],
 ]
```

But I also need to specify a term, that it should be searching within registrations for a certain event. I have a keyword field for that in my index: **event_id**.

How can I add this term (event_id) to the current search request?

PS: **Filtered** has been removed (replaced by **bool**, but it doesn't support **query_string**)

Or would it be better to specify a different index type: **_type** for each event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `bool/filter` you can definitely include a `query_string` and a `term` query. Try like this:

```
'query' => [
     'bool' => [
         'filter' => [
             [
                'query_string' => [
                  'query' => $query,
                  'fields'=> ['name', 'lastName', 'email', ...]
                ],
             ],
             [
                'term' => [
                  'event_id' => '123'
                ]
             ]
         ]
     ]
 ]
```

Comment: I've tried this but it seems like it doesn't affect search results. Doesn't matter what I'm looking for, it gives the same results

Comment: How are you sending your query?

Comment: Ok, your code seems fine to me. Can you also add the mapping of your `registrations` index? What makes you think that the results don't change? Can you show one specific query that you're making and a sample document you get that shouldn't match?

Comment: it was my mistake. After reviewing my code, I found a bug on my client. It wasn't updating search results for an empty result, so looked like it doesn't search. Thanks a lot for your help!